# Library for parsing CSV data

Tags: c++, parsing, csv

Please review my C++ CSV parsing class.

I have some specific questions:

1. Should `get_next_record` be a static function?
2. `CsvParser` implies values will be separated by commas so is a field separator constructor over the top?
3. `record.clear()` at the beginning of `get_next_record`.  Any other ways of solving the problem of removing last record. I realise that you could return record, but then you have the problem of how to deal with EOF or a stream error.

`CsvParser.hpp`

```
#ifndef CSV_PARSER_HPP_
#define CSV_PARSER_HPP_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using Field = std::string;
using Record = std::vector<Field>;
using Records = std::vector<Record>;

class CsvParser {
public:
    CsvParser(char field_separator = ',');
    bool get_next_record(std::istream& istrm, Record& record) const;

private:
    char field_separator_char;
};

#endif // CSV_PARSER_HPP_
```

`CsvParser.cpp`

```
#include "CsvParser.hpp"

CsvParser::CsvParser(char field_separator) : field_separator_char(field_separator) {}

bool CsvParser::get_next_record(std::istream& istrm, Record& record) const {

    // Having to clear record because otherwise the program will keep pushing back
    // fields into the vector feels dirty.  How could this be improved?
    record.clear();
    bool in_quotes = false;
    Field field;
    int ch;
    while (istrm) {
        ch = istrm.get();
        if (ch == EOF || (ch == '\n' && !in_quotes)) {
            if (ch == EOF && record.empty() && field.empty()) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                record.push_back(field);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (ch == field_separator_char && !in_quotes) {
            record.push_back(field);
            field.clear();
        }
        else if (ch == '"') {
            if (!in_quotes) {
                in_quotes = true;
            }
            else {
                // Could be an embedded " if next symbol not comma
                int nextch = istrm.peek();
                if (nextch != field_separator_char && nextch != '\n' && nextch != EOF) {
                    field += static_cast<char>(ch);
                }
                else {
                    in_quotes = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (ch == '\r') {
            if (in_quotes) {
                field += static_cast<char>(ch);
            }
        }
        else {
            field += static_cast<char>(ch);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Exercising using google test:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "CsvParser.hpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class CsvParserTest : public ::testing::Test {
public:
    CsvParser parser;
};

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, EmptyRecord) {

    const std::string csv{ "" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_FALSE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 0u);
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, SimpleSingleRecord) {

  const std::string csv{ "AA,BB,CC" };
  std::stringstream strm(csv);
  Record record;

  EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
  EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
  EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "AA");
  EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "BB");
  EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CC");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, SimpleTwoRecord) {

    const std::string csv{ "AA,BB,CC\r\nDD,EE,FF" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "AA");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "BB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CC");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "DD");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "EE");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "FF");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, SimpleQuotedField) {

    const std::string csv{ "\"A\",BB,CCC" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "A");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "BB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CCC");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, QuotesEmbeddedInQuotedField) {

    const std::string csv{ "\"\"A\"\",BB,CCC" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "\"A\"");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "BB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CCC");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, LinefeedEmbeddedInQuotedField) {

    const std::string csv{ "\"\"A\n\"\",BB,CCC" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "\"A\n\"");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "BB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CCC");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, CommaEmbeddedInQuotedField) {

    const std::string csv{ R"(""A,"",BB,CCC)" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], R"("A,")");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "BB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CCC");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, EmptyRow) {

    const std::string csv{ ",," };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0].size(), 0u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1].size(), 0u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2].size(), 0u);
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, QuotedFollowedByTwoEmptyFields) {

    const std::string csv{ "\"A\n\n\nB\",," };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "A\n\n\nB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1].size(), 0u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2].size(), 0u);
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, EmptyThenQuotedThenEmptyField) {

    const std::string csv{ ",\"A\n\n\nB\"," };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0].size(), 0u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "A\n\n\nB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2].size(), 0u);
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, EmptyEmptyThenQuoted) {

    const std::string csv{ ",,\"A\n\n\nB\"" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0].size(), 0u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1].size(), 0u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "A\n\n\nB");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, CRLFEndOfLIne) {

    const std::string csv{ "A,B,C\r\nD,E,F" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "A");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "B");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "C");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "D");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "E");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "F");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, EmbeddedCRLF) {

    const std::string csv{ "A,\"B\r\nC\",D\r\nE,F,G" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "A");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "B\r\nC");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "D");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "E");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "F");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "G");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, Complex) {

    const std::string csv = "AAA,BB,CCC\nDDD,EE,FFF\n\"A A\",\"B\nB\",CC\n\"A,B,C\",\"D         E\",F\n\"Billy \"Da Man\" Hooker\",,\n,,\n,,\"Yo bitches!\"\n,,\"Holler if you luv dem \"hat\" bitches\"\n,\"These are my long\nnotes on a load\nof stuff\n fancy some commas:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\",";

    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "AAA");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "BB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CCC");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "DDD");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "EE");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "FFF");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "A A");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "B\nB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CC");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "A,B,C");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "D         E");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "F");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "Billy \"Da Man\" Hooker");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "Yo bitches!");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "Holler if you luv dem \"hat\" bitches");

    EXPECT_TRUE(parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "These are my long\nnotes on a load\nof stuff\n fancy some commas:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "");
}

TEST_F(CsvParserTest, TabSeparated) {

    const std::string csv{ "AA\tBB\tCC\nDD\tEE\tFF" };
    std::stringstream strm(csv);
    Record record;
    CsvParser tab_parser('\t');

    EXPECT_TRUE(tab_parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "AA");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "BB");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "CC");

    EXPECT_TRUE(tab_parser.get_next_record(strm, record));
    EXPECT_EQ(record.size(), 3u);
    EXPECT_EQ(record[0], "DD");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[1], "EE");
    EXPECT_EQ(record[2], "FF");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is too low level and it lacks functionality.

It would be more idiomatic (and probably more efficient depending on circumstances) to use `std::getline` and extract the whole line from the stream. Then you can just find separators `,` one by one via `find_first_of` function of string and separate the line into array of strings.

This method might be lacking when there large rows in the csv file but the whole design of getting vector of strings is an even bigger victim of this case. Consider using a container buffer and vector of string views instead.

Lack of functionality: at times one has knowledge of the format of the csv file and want to perform conversion inplace instead of getting a vector of strings. If you could make a couple methods that satisfy common cases you need to support it would transform your csv library into a usable one.

Comment: CSV format uses embedded field and record separators so getline would not work (without modification anyway).

Comment: Could you give me some help on the couple methods that would satisfy common cases? Not sure what you have in mind?

Comment: @arcomber oh, the quotes. Damn. Well you can analyze if the last separator is inside quotes and repeat (with modification) getline with `"` and then with `\n` but that's indeed annoying. About common use cases - imagine user knows that expected format of rows is `int, int, double, string` and he wants to obtain the ints and double and store them in a vector of a class of his choice. To accomodate it, you can make method that converts the strings into tuple of `int,int,double,string` and pass it to the user defined function that converts to the type that the user needs.

Comment: Like tuple idea, will work on that.